# Defining time parameters in rails environment files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have lots of different timeouts for various cookies through out my app.
If I move these settings to be centralized in the Rails configuration files will they work properly since the environment variables is initialised only once when the application loads or am I mistaken?

In other words: will the timeout be set to when the cookie was created or will the timeout be set according to when the app loaded?

TODAY

```rb
cookies['locale'] = {
          :value   => current_user && current_user.locale || 'en',
          :expires => 1.week.from_now
        }
```

TOMORROW

```
cookies['locale'] = {
          :value   => current_user && current_user.locale || 'en',
          :expires => Application.config.locale_timeout
        }
```

config/environments/qa.rb

```rb
config.locale_timeout = 1.week.from_now
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In other words: will the timeout be set to when the cookie was created
>   or will the timeout be set according to when the app loaded

- the timeout be set according to when the app loaded

So, 
In my opinion, The correct way is to define Time offset in config:

```rb
Application.config.locale_timeout = 1.week
```

Then you will use it like this

```rb
:expires => Time.current + Application.config.locale_timeout
OR
:expires => Application.config.locale_timeout.from_now
```